# In a map how to collect keys of the same value into a vector?

Tags: c++

I want to collect keys of the same value in a map. What is the easiest way to do it using vector? That means all the keys having the same value can be collected in a vector.

Comment: You might also consider using a `multimap`, which seems better suited for you needs.

Answer (score 3):

You will have to do a linear search over the whole container, which is O(N).

```
std::vector<Value> values;
std::for_each(map.begin(), map.end(),
              [&](std::map<Key,Value>::value_type const & x) { 
                  if (x.second == value) 
                     values.push_back(x.first);
               });
```

If you want to extract all keys for which the value is not unique, the complexity of the code is higher, and you will need additional data, but you could do something like this:

```
std::map<Value, std::pair<Key, bool>> tracker;
    // Maps a 'Value' to the first 'Key' that had it, and a 'bool'
    // identifying if it has already been inserted into the vector.
std::vector<Key> keys;
for_each(m.begin(), m.end(), 
         [](std::map<Key, Value>::value_type const& x) {
             auto r = tracker.insert(std::make_pair(x.second,
                                          std::make_pair(x.first, false));
             if (!r.second) {
                // Not the first time we saw this value
                if (!r.first->second) {
                   // First key not already inserted, insert now and update flag
                   keys.push_back(r.first);
                   r.first->second = true;
                }
                keys.push_back(x.first);
             }
         });
```

Although in real code I would avoid using `std::pair` and would create a named type that makes the code simpler to read. In the code above it is not obvious what all those `first` and `second` mean…

A different alternative, probably more efficient (measure and profile) would be to use transform to create a vector where the elements are swapped and then iterate over that vector extracting the values of interest.

Comment: what if I do not know the values ahead of time?

Comment: You might need to clarify the question and what exactly you are looking for. Do you want to extract all keys for which the value is not unique?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it the following way

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <map>

int main() 
{
    std::map<int, std::string> m 
    { 
        { 1, "Monday" }, { 2, "Tuesday" }, { 9, "Monday" } 
    };

    std::vector<int> v;

    size_t n = 0;

    std::string s( "Monday" );

    for ( const auto &p : m ) 
    {
        if ( p.second == s ) ++n;
    }

    v.reserve( n );

    for ( const auto &p : m ) 
    {
        if ( p.second == s ) v.push_back( p.first );
    }

    for ( const auto &x : v ) std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
1 9
```

You can substitute the range based for statements for correspondingly `std::count_if` and `std::for_each` algorithms along with lambda expressions. But in my opiniion for this simple task it is better to use the range based for statements.

Comment: Iterating over the map twice just to reserve space in the vector seems like premature optimisation to me.

Comment: @Tristan Brindle It is a good idea to iterate the map twice instead of to reallocate memory n times.

Answer (score 0):

Where you are creating the `map`, consider creating a `unordered_multimap` with the key and value of the original `map` swapped.